# drop down filtering using subpages from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y91dn.png)
the problem is ,if i select the drop down it has to filter the data according to dropdown, which needs template and application form. but there is a problem with javascript.it didn't works fine. didn't able to filter.
messed up with javascript and php. i cant able to find the problem. below is the php code and javascript.
javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function addRemoveClass(theRows) {

        theRows.removeClass("odd even");
        theRows.filter(":odd").addClass("odd");
        theRows.filter(":even").addClass("even");
    }

    var rows = $("table#myTable tr:not(:first-child)");

    addRemoveClass(rows);


    $("#selectField").on("change", function() {

        var selected = this.value;

        if (selected != "All") {

            rows.filter("[position=" + selected + "]").show();
            rows.not("[position=" + selected + "]").hide();
            var visibleRows = rows.filter("[position=" + selected + "]");
            addRemoveClass(visibleRows);
        } else {

            rows.show();
            addRemoveClass(rows);

        }
```

html & php

```
       <select id="selectField">
                <option value="All" selected>All</option>
                <option value="Special">Special Needs Template</option>
                <option value="Application">Application Form</option>


            </select>
<table width="95%" border="0"  cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" id="myTable" class="table_fullwidth">
<tr><th width="15.8%">Application</th><th width="6%">Sequence</th><th width="22%">Group</th>
<th width="18%">Field</th><th width="20%">Description</th><th width="7%">Align</th><th width="6%">Allow Null</th><th width="6%">Edit</th>
</tr>





<div id ="table-filter">

<?php $i=1;
while ($myrow1 = DB_fetch_array($result)) { 
 if ($i % 2==0) $bkg='td1'; else $bkg='td2';
?>


<tr position="Special"  id="trow_<?php echo $i;?>" class="<?php echo $bkg;?> ">
<td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="cur_id_<?php echo $i;?>" id="cur_id_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $myrow1['id'];?>">



<input tabindex="<?php echo $i;?>_2" class="sel_long1 required" type="text" name="field1<?php echo $i;?>" id="field1_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $myrow1['appd'] ;?>" readonly>  </td>




<td align="center" ><input class="sel_long1 required" type="text"  value="<?php echo $myrow1['sequence']; ?>" name="field2<?php echo $i; ?>" id="field2_<?php echo $i; ?>" ></td>




<td align="center" ><?php

$sql1 = "SELECT id, descr, lang FROM enr_applicationgroup1 WHERE  lang =".$_SESSION['lang']." order by seq";
$result1= DB_query($sql1,$db);
?>
<select class="sel_long1 required"  name="field3<?php echo $i; ?>" id="field3_<?php echo $i; ?>"  >
<?php
while ($row1 = DB_fetch_array($result1)) {?>
<option <?php if ($myrow1['groupid']==$row1['id']) {?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="<?php echo $row1['id'];?>"  ><?php echo $row1['descr'];?><?php }?></option>

</select></td>


<td align="center"><?php

$sql1 = "select * from wiz_dbtags where lang=".$_SESSION['lang']." and hide=0 and dbaseid=2  and rtrim(ltrim(tablename)) in (".$tablename.")  order by description asc";

$result1= DB_query($sql1,$db);
?>

<select class="sel_long1 required"  name="field4<?php echo $i; ?>" id="field4_<?php echo $i; ?>"  >
<?php
while ($row1 = DB_fetch_array($result1)) {?>
<option <?php if ($myrow1['tagid']==$row1['id']) {?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="<?php echo $row1['id'].'_'.$row1['description'];?>"  ><?php echo $row1['description'];?><?php }?></option>

</select></td>




<td align="center" width="17%"><input class="sel_long1 required" type="text"  value="<?php echo $myrow1['description']; ?>" name="field5<?php echo $i; ?>" id="field5_<?php echo $i; ?>" ></td>

<td align="center" >
<select class="sel_long1 required" name="field6<?php echo $i; ?>"  id="field6_<?php echo $i; ?>" >
<option <?php if ($myrow1['align']==1) {?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="1"  > Center</option>
<option <?php if ($myrow1['align']==2) {?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="2"  >Left</option>
<option <?php if ($myrow1['align']==3) {?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="3"  >Right</option>

</select></td>


<td align="center"><input <?php if ($myrow1['oraseq']==1) echo 'disabled'; if ($myrow1['allownull']==1)echo 'checked';?>  type="checkbox" name="field7<?php echo $i; ?>" id="field7_<?php echo $i; ?>" >
</td>
<td align="center" width="8%"><input <?php  if ($myrow1['allowedit']==1)echo 'checked';?>  type="checkbox" name="field8<?php echo $i; ?>" id="field8_<?php echo $i; ?>" >
</td>




<td align="center"> <img src="<?php echo $site_path;?>images/del.png" width="20" class="cur" title="Delete" onclick="deleteitem('<?php echo $myrow1['id'];?>');"></td> 
</tr>
<?php
$i++;

}





$breakdown = $_POST['breakdown']+$num_rows;
$j=$num_rows+1;
```

Comment: Your code is not helping ! Show some screenshots as well showing what you expect and what is happening right now !

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai [Please be kind](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). The code is very useful. Let's not scare new users away :-) A screenshot would be good, I agree.

Comment: ok. i put the screen shot

Comment: @NoelWidmer : Ofcourse, Kind apologies Dear OP ! But I think some graphical explanation will really help in getting to know things easily ! :)

Comment: sorry..i m new to stackoverflow

Comment: marked with a blue color on dropdown has to be changed according to the values

Comment: Thank you for the image. We all were new users at some point :) Now we are here to help you with your problem as well as the way you are asking for help. And of course we are here to learn as well. StackOverflow is not only for getting help on **hard skills**. You'll also learn many **soft skills** (especially about communication) while you are here. Have a good time :-)

Comment: I would recommend to properly indent your code along write clear and nice code !

Comment: When OP learns how to ask for help he will learn how to solve the problem without us. It's about skills of working with code and with the meanings of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what's wrong with your code but here I wrote a clear code for you which will pretty much do what you are doing! Now go ahead and modify it accordingly for your own needs ! :P

**NOTE :** It's a different approach ! It doesn't use `.filter()`. You can always do the simple way. Try to not make things complex by involving too many things. Always think of the easiest and clear solution ! Use `.show()` and `.hide()` instead.

Here it is :

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').on('change',function(){
   if (this.value == "") {
    $('tr').show();
   }
   if (this.value == "even") {
    $('tr').show();
    $('tr:nth-child(even)').hide();
   }
   if (this.value == "odd") {
    $('tr').show();
    $('tr:nth-child(odd)').hide();
   }
   if (this.value == "special") {
    $('tr').show();
    $('tr.special').hide();
   }
  });
 });
```

```css
table {margin-top:100px;border-collapse: collapse;}
th,td {border: 1px solid gray;padding: 10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HIDE : <select>
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="even">Even</option>
 <option value="odd">Odd</option>
 <option value="special">Special</option>
</select>

<table>
<tr>
 <th>ODD</th>
 <th>ODD</th>
 <th>ODD</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>EVEN</td>
 <td>EVEN</td>
 <td>EVEN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>ODD</td>
 <td>ODD</td>
 <td>ODD</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>EVEN</td>
 <td>EVEN</td>
 <td>EVEN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>ODD</td>
 <td>ODD</td>
 <td>ODD</td>
</tr>
<tr class="special">
 <td>SPECIAL BUT STILL EVEN</td>
 <td>SPECIAL BUT STILL EVEN</td>
 <td>SPECIAL BUT STILL EVEN</td>
</tr>
<tr class="special">
 <td>SPECIAL BUT STILL ODD</td>
 <td>SPECIAL BUT STILL ODD</td>
 <td>SPECIAL BUT STILL ODD</td>
</tr>
<tr class="special">
 <td>SPECIAL BUT STILL EVEN</td>
 <td>SPECIAL BUT STILL EVEN</td>
 <td>SPECIAL BUT STILL EVEN</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE :**

For to use it with database so you need to add classes to your different records which belongs to your 3 values of dropdown as **(Assuming that `$result` holds data in array format from your Database)** :

```
<?php
foreach ($result as $record) {
    if ($record['type'] == "application") { $class = "application"; }
    if ($record['type'] == "special") { $class = "special"; }
    echo "<tr class='".$class."'></tr>";
 }
?>
```

Then you can do it like this way in `JS` as :

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    if (this.value == "all") {
        $('tr').show();
    }
    if (this.value == "application") {
        $('tr').hide();
        $('tr.application').show();
    }
    if (this.value == "special") {
        $('tr').hide();
        $('tr.special').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, i got the idea, but how to use this technique according to the database values?

Comment: @user8602072 : Please accept the answer to consider this question solved if it helped you.

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\hr\setup\datawizards_sub.php on line 114..showing this error.

Comment: @user8602072 : Is this your own script or you are editing someone else software/script? You need to use your own array instead of `$result` which holds your db data.!

Comment: @user8602072 : Glad ! I could help.